# accessing text box of Form1 from another cpp file, Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express. I have a form (Form1.h) that contains a text box (textBox1).

I want another test.cpp to be able to access to textBox1 and display the message.

I have something like:

in Form1.h

```
... standard form code generated by Visual Studio

private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;

private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{ 
   textBox1->Text = "Connecting to server ...";
}
```

And in test.cpp contains something like

```
....

void write (const unsigned char *data, int length)
{ 
   System::Windows::Forms::textBox1->Text = "Send failed";
}
....
```

After compiling, I have got the following errors:

- 'textBox1' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms'
- 'textBox1' : undeclared identifier
- left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
- syntax error : missing ';' before 'string'

I am new to Visual C++ and don't know how to access class/object properly.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the compiler issues can be resolved by changing:

System::Windows::Forms::textBox1 to just textBox1

Another way of thinking is textBox1 is a managed (^) pointer of type System::Windows::Forms::TextBox.

Other typos may still be present. The snippets above appear to be in C++/.NET. This is a different beast from 'regular' C++.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I have seen another link that tried to do something similar but using a function defined in test.cpp and call it in Form1.  For me I want to use call it in test.cpp. The link is:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980056/change-label-text-from-different-header-file-visual-c-2010

Comment: Ah... Well that SO answer seems reasonable. As the writer of the answer stated, textbox is private to the Form1 class, so an accessor function is required.

Comment: How do I call it inside test.cpp ?